# Javascript Alert box within iframe

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I am very new to javascript and I am using the code below to output an alert box. I'm not sure why but the alert box does not seem to work inside the function but will work quite happily outside of it. How would I make it appear from within this function?

I feel I should also mention the code below is being executed within an iframe itself.

Any help appreciated

```js
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});


function yourFunction(){

    alert("Alert");

    document.getElementById('iframeA').src = document.getElementById('iframeA').src

    setTimeout(yourFunction, 3000);

}      


function yourFunctionTwo(){

    document.getElementById('iframeB').src = document.getElementById('iframeB').src


    setTimeout(yourFunctionTwo, 4000);
}


yourFunction();
yourFunctionTwo();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    
</head>

<iframe id="iframeA" src="" height="50%" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframeB" src="/sms/frames/tickerB.php" height="50%" width="100%" style="display: block; position: absolute;"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframeA" src="/sms/frames/tickerA.php" height="50%" width="100%" style="display: block; position: absolute;"></iframe>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to open your javascript console to debug.

When you uncomment this line:

```
document.getElementById('iframeA').src = document.getElementById('iframeA').src
```

It will work. I see two times the same id **iframesA** in your html!

Try to replace the `alert()` with a `console.log("iframesA");`

Also you can do a setInterval, outside the function:

```
setInterval(yourFunction, 3000);
```

I made a JSBin
http://jsbin.com/rixigicugu/edit?html,js,output

Note: I think its not a good way to dispay your pages. Iframe will have big problems with https or mixed http / https sites...

Answer (score 0):

Alert in javascript should be used in the whole page and not only in inside a frame. If you want to use alert on a frame, use modal instead.